# postgres update value based on count of associated join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sql-update, subquery

I have a simple scenario TableA, TableB and JoinTable that joins TableA and TableB. I want to store in TableA for each row in TableA the count of records in JoinTable that have TableAId. I can select it correctly as follows:

```
SELECT "Id", (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "JoinTable" WHERE "JoinTable"."TableAId" = "TableA"."Id") 
AS TOT FROM "TableA" LIMIT 100
```

However I'm having a hard time writing an update query. I want to update TableA.JoinCount with this result.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update tablea a
set tot = (
    select count(*)
    from jointable j
    where t.tableaid = a.id
)
```

This updates all rows of `tablea` with the count of matches from `jointable`; if there are not matches, `tot` is set to `0`.

I would not necessarily, however, recommend storing such derived information. While it can easily be intialized with the above statement, maintaining it is tedious. You will soon find yourself creating triggers for every DML operation on the join table (update, delete, insert). Instead, you could put the information in a view:

```
create view viewa as
select id, 
    (select count(*) from jointable j where j.tableaid = a.id) as tot
from tablea a
```

Side note: in general, don't use quoted identifiers in Postgres. This [this link](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the group by query as the source for an UPDATE statement:

```
update "TableA" a
  set "JoinCount" = t.cnt
from (
  select "TableAId" as id, count(*) as cnt
  from "JoinTable" 
  group by "TableAId"
) t  
WHERE t.id = a."Id"
```